# Vue-apexcharts supported versions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What are the supported version in [vue-apexcharts](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts) for "Windows", "Linux", "Mac", "Android", "IOS" and "Tablet"

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a Vue project that will be used on the Web.
There is no support per-se for Windows/Linux/MacOS/Android/iOS since those are OSes.
"Tablet" is more of a device size too.

You probably meant browser support?
The answer to that is probably: all the evegreen browsers (Firefox, Chrome etc...) + most Safari.
Forget Internet Explorer (since it's dead) and some chinese browsers I guess.

For more details, you would need to double check a specific spec in CSS on [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/).
For JS, it will usually be [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).